# the first letter then every second letter or space of the original string

Tags: javascript, string

Ask the user to enter a string. 
Print a new string composed as follows: 
the first letter, then every other letter(every second letter) or space of the original string. 
presented the example below  (Eg `'Airplane' => 'Arln' ; 'Good Day'  => 'Go a'`)

```
var str=prompt("Insert string");
for(var i=1;i<=str.length;i=i+2){
  var str1=str.push[i];
  var newStr=str.splice[str[i],str.length-1];
}
console.log(newStr);
```

Comment: array starts with 0 and not 1. What's the issue with above code? What output do you get ?

Comment: And `i<=str.length` will give you an array offset error

Answer (score 1):

Based from your code, try:

```
var str = prompt("Insert string");
var newStr = '';
for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i = i + 2){
  newStr += str[i];
}
console.log(newStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way.Use [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
var str = 'Airplane';

    str.split('').filter(function(val,key){  

        return key%2==0;

    }).join('');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
var str = "Good Day";
var res = str.split("").filter(function(str, index) {
    return index % 2 == 0; 
}).join('');
```

Example https://jsfiddle.net/mo44dhyq/

`.split('')` - It will split the string into an array by each letter and return the array ([documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)).

`.filter(function(str, index) {return index % 2 == 0; })` - This will iterate over the elements in the array (Returned from the `split()` function) and return only the even indexes ([documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp)).

`.join('')` - Join the results of the `filter()` function into a new string ([documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp)).

Answer (score 0):

A variable declared inside `for` cycle will be available only in that context, so `console.log(newStr)` will print `undefined`. To be able to "save your work" you should define some variable outside of for cycle.

Here is an example:

```
var str=prompt("Insert string");
var newStr = str[0];

for(var i=1; i<=str.length+2; i=i+2){
  newStr = newStr + str[i];
}
console.log(newStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `String.split` and `Array.forEach` functions:

```
var str = 'Airplane',
    arr = str.split(""), cutted = "";

arr.forEach((v, k) => (k % 2 !== 0) || (cutted += v)); // ES6 arrow function expression
console.log(cutted);   // "Arln"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression and an apropriate replace.

Edit: Proposal with spaces.

```js
document.write('<pre>' + 'Airplane'.replace(/(.)./g, '$1') + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + 'Good Day'.replace(/(.)./g, '$1') + '</pre>');

document.write('<pre>' + 'Airplane'.replace(/(.)./g, '$1 ') + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + 'Good Day'.replace(/(.)./g, '$1 ') + '</pre>');
```

Comment: If the input is "Goood Day" I think the OP wants "God a" as output.  However `'Goood Day'.replace(/(.)(.)/g, '$1')` produces "GodDy"

Comment: @Redu, you have one `o` to much.

Comment: That extra "o" was to demonstrate the problem in the regex. The OP wants the spaces to remain as far as how i understood from the question phrasing.

Comment: @Redu, the examples show strings with skipped every 2nd letter, like my above proposal. if the op wants spaces, then op has made it clear in the examples.

Comment: Yes true those two examples fit the pattern of both what you think and i think. However OP doesn't mention skipping. OP says s/he (JeJe?) wants (first letter) and (every other letter or space) in the original string. Otherwise your solution is ingenious.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111361/discussion-between-redu-and-nina-scholz).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple code:

```
var str = prompt("Insert string"),
    str = str.split(''),
    str1 = " ",
    len = str.length;

for(var i=0; i < len ;i++){
  var newStr=str.splice(0,1);
  if((i%2) === 0) {
    str1 = str1 + newStr[0];
  }
}
console.log(str1);
```

I hope this should the problem.
First convert the string into an array of characters using    `split`,    then iterate through the array. Remember    `splice`    returns an array and affects the original array.